# How to ping with duration 60 seconds in CMD Windows 10

Tags: cmd

How do I ping for 60 seconds in CMD?

```
ping www.google.com -t60
```

Doesn't works.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `ping -?` and read the output help. Whatever you want to find out with sending ICMP ECHO requests to a device/server for a time period of 60 seconds and waiting for the ICMP ECHO responses which the device/server might not send at all or might send quickly or delayed with various delays depending on its load, it is the wrong approach using `%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe` and ICMP ECHO. Your question is also off topic according to the help topic [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: well, As stated by @Mofi, `ping /?` or `ping -?` has some good info, there is a section which states `-n count  Number of echo requests to send` so you'll benefit from  `ping www.google.com -n 60`

Answer (score 1):

The command is working but not as you wanted since -t flag is for continuous ping unless stopped.

I think this ping feature you are looking for is available in Linux

It uses -i flag for interval from what I recall.